# Delete an outdated image from the caches folder

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have an image that returns from my web service. I save the image in the following format:

```
LOGO_3100B874-4D92-E211-AAF5-001A6426DE62_20140908095804_BIG_HD.GIF
```

Now if someone updates an image on my server, the date parameter changes like so:

```
LOGO_3100B874-4D92-E211-AAF5-001A6426DE62_20140908095895_BIG_HD.GIF
```

Now the code I have will use the most recent image just fine (because the file does not exists) Now, I can't figure out how I would go about finding that old image file path and removing it from the caches folder. How would I go about doing that? Here's the code I use to save  the phone:

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/logos/LOGO_%@_%@_%@_%@.GIF",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"urlIMG"],exhibtorKeyId,formatedDate,PhotoSize,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"screenResolution"]]];

NSString *imagePath = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"LOGO_%@_%@_%@_%@.GIF",exhibtorKeyId,formatedDate,PhotoSize,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"screenResolution"]]];




NSString *imgurl;

if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath])
{

    NSString * oldImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LOGO_%@_%@_%@",exhibtorKeyId,PhotoSize,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"screenResolution"]];

#define PATH [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]


    NSString * oldImageFilePath = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:oldImageName];


    NSString *pathAndFileName = ??//How would I get the file with the old date? 
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathAndFileName])
    {
        NSLog(@"Rmove Image");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"File not found");
    }

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];

    if(!error)
    {
        [data writeToFile:imagePath options:0 error:&error];
        image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    }
    else
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_profile.png"];
    }

}
else

     image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    imgurl = model.customText1;
```

Hopefully I am making sense. Thanks!

Comment: Come up with a naming scheme so older versions can be identified. Perhaps if you need all that information create a class to hold the metadata and the image and save instances of that class with `NSArchiver`. This is a perfect example of why encoding information into a name is a bad idea. BTW, a single statement 270 characters long: Wow!

Comment: There's a method behind my madness of naming the image 27 characters zaph :). Will look into NSrArchiver.

Comment: I'm sure there is. We learned a long time ago not to do that in databases. Invariably going forward there is a problem. But it is amazing that in software development, as opposed to professions, we do not benefit from our past learning but keep making the same mistakes. Not just here but in general.

Comment: If you understood the business logic I am sure it would make sense to you. Won't bother explaining it here. Yeah I agree. Well I think thats the beauty behind software development, there are a variety of combinations to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out an approach. I am storing the previous image path in the NSUserDefaults. Here's the code to follow:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/logos/LOGO_%@_%@_%@_%@.GIF",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"urlIMG"],exhibtorKeyId,formatedDate,PhotoSize,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"screenResolution"]]];


    NSString *imagePath = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"LOGO_%@_%@_%@_%@.GIF",exhibtorKeyId,formatedDate,PhotoSize,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"screenResolution"]]];



    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {

        NSString * oldImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LOGO_%@_%@_%@",exhibtorKeyId,PhotoSize,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"screenResolution"]];


        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:oldImageName]) {

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSString *removeItemPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:oldImageName];

            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:removeItemPath error:&error];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:nil forKey:oldImageName];

        }


    }
    NSString *imgurl;

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath])
    {    
        NSString * oldImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LOGO_%@_%@_%@",exhibtorKeyId,PhotoSize,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"screenResolution"]];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:imagePath forKey:oldImageName];

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];

        if(!error)
        {
            [data writeToFile:imagePath options:0 error:&error];
            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        }
        else
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_profile.png"];
        }

    }
    else
         image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```